# Noun that means "To not take advantage of anyone"

Tags: synonyms

I am writing an essay on *To Kill A Mockingbird* and need a noun that is synonymous with "not taking advantage of anyone" as I need to be able to say: Scout learns [Insert the noun here].

Comment: Why not just use the noun phrase you have used in your question?  "Scout learns not to take advantage of anyone" seems fine to me, if that's what you want to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my thinking, someone who does not take advantage of others is *trustworthy* or has *integrity*.

similar words: honesty, truthfulness, reliability, dependability, honor, uprightness, (to be) principled, true, truthfulness, ethical, virtue, incorruptibility,, unimpeachibility, (to be) above suspicion; moral uprightness.
righteousness, morality, decency, fairness, scrupulousness, sincerity, trustworthiness.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear to me why you need a noun there, so the following isn't limited to nouns.  You may be able to use words like the following:
• adjective *[unselfish](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unselfish)*, “Not selfish; selfless; generous; altruistic”, eg, “Scout learns to be unselfish” or “Scout learns to be less selfish”.
 • noun *[selflessness](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/selflessness)*, “Not selfish; selfless; generous; altruistic”, where *[selfless](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/selfless#Adjective)* means “Having, exhibiting, or motivated by no concern for oneself but for others; unselfish”
• noun *[charity](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/charity#Noun)*, in its sense “an attitude of [kindness](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kindness#Noun) and understanding towards others, now especially suggesting generosity”
• noun *[deference](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deference#Noun)*, in its sense  “The willingness to carry out the wishes of others”
• noun *[self-restraint](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/self-restraint#Noun)*, “Self-control, control over one's emotions, passions and actions”

Also see *[altruistic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/altruistic#Adjective)*, *[unprejudiced](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unprejudiced)*, *[dispassionate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dispassionate#Adjective)*, and *[disinterested](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disinterested#Adjective)*.